# Annotation - Place or Unplace in bulk

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, annotation

Using ArcMap 10.3.

I am trying to change 100+ annotation values from "Placed" to "Unplaced" as quick as possible.

I have tried to select them and use field calculator, but keep getting an error for Empty Values. The only way I can get it to change is to individually click each attribute and use the drop drown box to change it to place/unplaced.

Comment: You can do it in the attribute table -> sort then select all unplaced -> use calculator to change values.  The values are numeric -1,1 and 0  don't remember exactly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use your field calculator.  unplaced = 0 placed =1.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  I think your answer is in the right direction, but it needs more info.  Please **[edit]** your answer to include details as to where and how to do what you're suggesting, and why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

In the editing bar > attribute button > attribute tab

Just like you would do a bulk text size chang. Select the annotation file title and select unplace/place.

This will change all selected.